# parse.com Cloud Code parsing RSS CDATA background job

Tags: javascript, rss, cloud, parse-platform

I'm learning parse.com Cloud Code. And I wanted to create background job which makes http request for RSS feed. After I get RSS feed I need to parse it to get values which I want to store in rows. At parse.com forum they sugeested that to parse RSS feed we should use xmlreader.js and sax.js to parse this RSS feed. I also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309519/how-can-i-convert-background-jobs-to-something-like-functions) question to create bg job and it was succesfull I'm saving tags from this feed like title, link and pubDate, but my problem is that my RSS feed have CDATA in description tag, where is multiple information like *Region,Price, Address,Rooms* and I don't know how to parse this CDATA to get these values so I can stroe them in rows like title or link tags.

Here is part from my RSS feed:

```
<item>
<link>
http://www.ss.lv/msg/lv/real-estate/flats/riga/centre/bilikf.html
</link>
<pubDate>Mon, 19 May 2014 14:12:29 +0300</pubDate>
<description>
<![CDATA[
<a href="http://www.ss.lv/msg/lv/real-estate/flats/riga/centre/bilikf.html"><img align=right border=0 src="http://i.ss.lv/images/2014-04-16/337180/VH4OHU9rSVQ=/1.t.jpg" width="160" height="120" alt=""></a>
 Region: <b>centrs</b><br/>Adress: <b>Brīvības 98</b><br/>Rooms.: <b>3</b><br/>m2: <b>80</b><br/>Sērija: <b>Renov.</b><br/>: <b>7.50 €<br><div class=cc2>5.27 Ls</div></b><br/>Price: <b>600 €/mēn.<br><div class=cc2>422 Ls/mēn.</div></b><br/><br/><b><a href="http://www.ss.lv/msg/lv/real-estate/flats/riga/centre/bilikf.html">Apskatīt sludinājumu</a></b><br/><br/>
]]>
</description>
</item>
```

And here is my background job where I parse title, pubDate and link tags, but I don't know how to parse description tag to get other values.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("bgJob", function(request, status) {
  // 
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  //make http request
  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: 'http://www.ss.lv/lv/real-estate/flats/riga/hand_over/rss/'
  }).then (function(httpResponse) {
    var soapData = httpResponse.text;

    xmlreader.read(soapData, function (err, xmldata) {
         if(err) {
                response.error("Error " +err);
                return console.log(err);
            } 

        var info = [];
        xmldata.rss.channel.item.each(function (i, item) {
            var dzivokli = new Dzivokli();
            dzivokli.set("link", item.link.text());
            dzivokli.set("title", item.title.text());
            dzivokli.set("pubDate", item.pubDate.text());          
            listArray.push(dzivokli);
        });

        var promises = [];
            Parse.Object.saveAll(info, {
                    success: function(objs) {
                        promises.push(objs);
                        console.log("SAVED ALL!");
                    },
                    error: function(error) { 
                        console.log("ERROR WHILE SAVING - "+error);
                    }   
                });
            return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
  });

  }).then(function() {
    // Set the job's success status
    status.success("RSS feeds tika requestots");
  }, function(error) {
    // Set the job's error status
    status.error("something went wrong.");
  });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't a parse.com question, but more of how to parse CDATA text with javascript. Since you are just getting the raw html text you could just create jquery object and get the data that way. [Parse a HTML String with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-a-html-string-with-js).

You could also try regular expressions to get the data you want.

Comment: The problem is that I red in parse.com forum that cloud code doesn't suport jQuery. And when I tryed to save this xml into string so I can parse it using getElementsByTagName() then I got TypeError: Object in my cloud code console  under job status.